# Creating a Spring DataSource for connecting to Google Cloud SQL

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, jdbc, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to find the best way to create a dataSource in Spring for connecting to a Google Cloud SQL instance.

I'm currently using:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:google:mysql://myappid:instanceId/mydb?user=myuser" />
    <property name="username" value="myuser" />
    <property name="password" value="mypassword" />
</bean>
```

However, I'm a little concerned about using the DriverManagerDataSource provided by Spring as it's documentation says it creates a new connection for every call.

Before migrating over to App Engine I was using a connection pool called BoneCP - however it uses classes that are restricted by App Engine. Is there a connection pool or some other data source class that is recommended to be used with Google Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [c3p0](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22c3p0%22%20AND%20a%3a%22c3p0%22) or [commons-dbcp](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22commons-dbcp%22%20AND%20a%3a%22commons-dbcp%22). They both implement javax.sql.Datasource which is [whitelisted by app-engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist).

Example on commons-dbcp:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:google:mysql://myappid:instanceId/mydb?user=myuser" />
    <property name="username" value="myuser" />
    <property name="password" value="mypassword" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
</bean>
```